NAV2 + MPPI will not switch direction at waypoint
I am working on a larger garden robot and need it to go navigateThroughPoses. One of the special situations is where the poses are in a path where the robot has to switch direction 180° and go backward. but it still hast to move to the pose before turning.
So if you look at the images. The poses sent to the navigateThroughPoses are leading to the end of the green line and directly back. It switch direction correctly, but it switches far before reaching the outmost pose.
I tried

Changing the radius in RemovePassedGoals of the navigate_through_poses BT
different pruning distances
different setting for threshold and offset_from_furthest for PathAlignCritic and PathFollowCritic
different vx and vx_std values

Can anyone point me in the right direction?


controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    controller_frequency: 10.0
    progress_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker"
      required_movement_radius: 0.2
      movement_time_allowance: 300.0
    general_goal_checker:
      stateful: True
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.3
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.3
    FollowPath:
      plugin: "nav2_mppi_controller::MPPIController"
      time_steps: 35
      model_dt: 0.1
      batch_size: 1000
      vx_max: 1.2
      vx_min: -1.2
      vx_std: 0.2
      vy_max: 0.0
      vy_std: 0.2
      wz_max: 1.6 #1.0
      wz_std: 0.3 #0.3
      ax_max: 2.0
      ax_min: -2.0
      iteration_count: 1
      prune_distance: 4.0
      transform_tolerance: 0.1
      temperature: 0.3
      gamma: 0.015
      motion_model: "DiffDrive"
      visualize: true
      reset_period: 3.0 # (only in Humble)
      TrajectoryVisualizer:
        trajectory_step: 5
        time_step: 3
      #AckermannConstrains:
      #  min_turning_r: 0.2
      critics: ["ConstraintCritic", "ObstaclesCritic", "GoalCritic", "GoalAngleCritic", "PathAlignCritic", "PathFollowCritic", "PathAngleCritic", "PreferForwardCritic"]
      
      PathAlignCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 2
        cost_weight: 14.0
        max_path_occupancy_ratio: 0.3 #0.3
        trajectory_point_step: 10
        threshold_to_consider: 4.0 #4.0
        offset_from_furthest: 15 #20
        use_path_orientations: false

      PathFollowCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 5.0 #10.0
        offset_from_furthest: 10
        threshold_to_consider: 2.0 #1.0

      PathAngleCritic:
        enabled: false
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 5.0
        offset_from_furthest: 10
        threshold_to_consider: 2.0
        max_angle_to_furthest: 1.0
        forward_preference: false
        mode: 0

      ObstaclesCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        repulsion_weight: 1.1
        critical_weight: 10.0
        consider_footprint: true
        collision_cost: 10000.0
        collision_margin_distance: 0.1
        near_goal_distance: 0.5
        inflation_radius: 0.1 # (only in Humble)
        cost_scaling_factor: 10.0 # (only in Humble)

      GoalCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 5.0
        threshold_to_consider: 1.0
        
      GoalAngleCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 3.0
        threshold_to_consider: 1.0

      ConstraintCritic:
        enabled: false
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 4.0

      PreferForwardCritic:
        enabled: false
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 1.0
        threshold_to_consider: 0.5

